# Arduino PID DC Motor Position Control

Tags: arduino, pid-controller

I'm doing a control engineering project, implementing a PID motor position control for automatic antenna tracking system. The system contain a dc motor, absolute encoder, and a motor driver.

Everything work as expected, but one thing. The motor cannot stop at set point value near 0 degree (350 - 359, 0 - 10 degree). The used code:

```
#include <PID_v1.h>
int RPWM = 5;
int LPWM = 6;
int L_EN = 7;
int R_EN = 8;
boolean pin_state[10];
byte input_pin[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13};
int dec_position = 0;
int dc = 0;
double kp = 50, ki = 45, kd = 2;
double input = 0, output = 0, setpoint = 0;
volatile long encoderPos = 0;
PID myPID(&input, &output, &setpoint, kp, ki, kd, DIRECT);

void setup() {
  pinMode(L_EN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(R_EN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RPWM, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LPWM, OUTPUT);
  for (byte i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    pinMode(input_pin[i], INPUT);
  }
  TCCR1B = TCCR1B & 0b11111000 | 1; 
  myPID.SetMode(AUTOMATIC);
  myPID.SetSampleTime(1);
  myPID.SetOutputLimits(-255, 255);          
  digitalWrite(L_EN, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(R_EN, HIGH);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    String baca = Serial.readString();
    setpoint = baca.toInt();
  }
  ReadEncoder();
  input = dc;
  myPID.Compute();
  pwmOut(output);
}

void pwmOut(int out) {
  if (out > 0) {
    analogWrite(RPWM, out);//Sets speed variable via PWM
  }
  else {
    analogWrite(LPWM, abs(out));//Sets speed variable via PWM
  }
}

void ReadEncoder() {
// FOR READING ENCODER POSITION, GIVING 0-359 OUTPUT CORRESPOND TO THE ENCODER POSITION
  for (byte i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    pin_state[i] = !(digitalRead(input_pin[i]));
  }
  dec_position = (pin_state[8] * 256) + (pin_state[7] * 128) + (pin_state[6] * 64) + (pin_state[5] * 32) + (pin_state[4] * 16) + (pin_state[3] * 8) + (pin_state[2] * 4) + (pin_state[1] * 2) + pin_state[0];
  dc = map(dec_position, 0, 500, 0, 360);
}
```

When the set point is a value between 10 - 350 the sytem worked well. But when it is not, the motor never stop rotating.

I know the problem is due to a little position overshoot cause the encoder to read a very large error.

For instance, if the setpoint is 0 degree, the motor rotate to reach it. Motor rotation is slowing down as its "now" position approaching 0 degree, but the system is not overshoot free. Therefore, even 1 degree overshoot cause the error value is -359 (set point - now position) and the motor rotate again to reach the desired position.

Need help how to overcome this problem. Sorry for bad english.

Comment: You posted a question to a site that is intended as a repository for answers for posterity, then you found the answer, and then you didn't make the effort to post the answer to help others that might be in the same situation?  Not cool.

Comment: the solution has been already posted. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution

```
double error; 
if (SP>PV) {
     if (abs(SP-PV) < abs(-360 + SP - PV)) error = SP - PV;
     else  error = -360 + SP - PV;
}
else{
     if(abs(SP-PV)< abs(360 - PV + SP)) error = SP - PV;
     else  error = 360 - SP + PV;
}
```

Instead off simple present value minus the set point for error. The code above return shortest path from present value to set point.

Answer (score -2):

i didn't read your code yet. However, to reach "set point" (SV) you should give for "present value" (PV) an error allowance (EA)

For example: EA = SV - PV.
             If EA = (-2,+2)degree then it reach "now position"

And, you should not use degree for angle, you should convert it to position (calculate by pulse)

Hope that concept can help you.

Comment: If you did not read the code in the question, you should not be answering the question.